# Finding out my User Agent on Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-agent, node-webkit

When using browser context in Node-Webkit, is there any way to find out what is the exact User Agent used for external requests, from within Node-Webkit?

Example: if Node-Webkit loads an image that's in an HTML from some remote, I would like to know what's the User Agent this remote will see.

Using a sniffer (Fiddler/Wireshark) is trivial, but I'm looking for a method to obtain this information directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that you can definitely do this:

```
iframeID.setAttribute('nwUserAgent', 'Super Browser');
```

Then I can't see why you can't also do this:

```
Agent = iframeID.getAttribute('nwUserAgent');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Could you elaborate on how do you get the iframeID for a browser window? `document.createElement('iframe').getAttribute('nwUserAgent');` returns `null`.